# Need Information about "Package Update Process"

Tags: linux, centos, updates, yum, rpm

When i issue the command "yum update" as root under CentOS, all updates will be installed. But what exactly happens during the update process. I am asking myself how a package gets updated.

For example:

Original Installed Package:
File A
File B

Package with update:
File A (still the same)
File B (has changed)

What happens now? Does "yum update" also overwrites File A or only File B?

Thanks four your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is regular file then B will be overwritten. If you mark it as `%config` in `%files` section then it is overwritten but previous version is preserved as B.rpmsave. When you use `%config(noreplace)` then B is kept untouched and new file is saved as B.rpmnew.

I simplified it, more verbose explanation can be found here: http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html